# Use of "yet another" in the middle of a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, determiners

Is the usage of *yet another* correct in the following sentence?

> This sentence might need **yet another** piece of work for you!

Where can I place *yet another* in a sentence?

Comment: In your sentence,  *yet* is an adverb modifying *another* and *another* is employed as an adjective, so the phrase comes immediately before the noun it modifies: *piece*.

Comment: @StoneyB "Another" is an article, not an adjective.

Comment: @JoeZeng  A 'determiner', if you like, which in the newer categorizations embraces the 'articles' and certain of what in the older categorization are called 'adjectives'; but I don't think the distinction is relevant here.

Comment: I like _determiner_, which makes 'yet' here a _determiner modifier_, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence would be clearer if rewritten as:

> This sentence might need yet another piece of work *from* you.

Or:

> This sentence might *require* yet another piece of work *from* you.

In other words, I don't believe "yet another" is the problematic part of the sentence here.

Comment: Or, *This sentence might **mean** yet another piece of work **for** you.*

Comment: You're right. "For" should not be the preposition. I'll use this expression more carefully in the future.

Comment: why `require` can be a better choice rather than `need`here?

Answer (score 2):

In this word couple, "yet" signifies repetition, or "again." You would therefore say "yet another" when "another" alone has already been used, and you want to indicate "another again."

Here's an example: "I know you already gave me a piece of pie, but now I want you to give me another. And I like it so much, I'll need yet another one later on!"

Here's another: His boss asked him for another report. Once he had turned that one in, his boss asked him for yet another.

Here's yet another example: Another meteor hit the ground, but Herman stood still. When yet another meteor landed right behind him, however, he ran.

Care for yet another? No? Then I'll stop there. But wait. Yet another point is that I should answer your question as to where can you use "yet another" in a sentence. The answer is you can place it anywhere; notice the examples I have already given? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use parentheses:

> This sentence may require (yet another) piece of work from you.

or you could omit "piece of" altogether, and just say "more":

> This sentence may require more work from you.